# Connect two C / C++ Projects with each other

Tags: c++, c, api, wrapper

I have a finished C project and a finished C++ project. Now I want to write an api for this, which can switch between the two projects.
I already know this variant:

```
extern "C" {
   void foo();
}
```

Unfortunately, I cannot make any changes to the projects.

*Is there a way to implement this without changing the existing code?*

I hope you can help me with this.

Comment: add a new C layer that calls the internal C++ functions. Don't change existing code, just add new code.

Comment: So these two libraries provide similar functionality, and you wish to provide a third library which exposes a single API and uses either library as a backend?

Comment: Probably makes more sense to link each of the projects as libraries then include whatever library that's required.

Answer (score 1):

There's hardly enough information, but I would suggest that the easiest way might be a third project into which both projects are either imported as [submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) or used as dependencies (require installation).

The approach might differ if either of the two projects compiles as a library, in which case consider "installing" them as dependencies and simply document the requirement.

If the either of the project are code repositories (to be used as source code), add the appropriate folders and files to the makefile in the third project and either use a submodule or copy the original project files (and its license).

Note the project licenses might add requirements of their own. These are important, as you want people to respect your work and the effort you put into your projects and this starts with respecting other people's work and the effort they put into their projects (or music / books / movies or whatever they do).